# JavaScript Text Replace Script Modification Assistance

Tags: javascript, jquery

1. How can I make the following script not do a replace if the string is wrapped in span tags with a class of "MFR_UIREF"?
2. The terms typed are currently case sensitive. How can I make it case insensitive (such that it will for instance change 'Application'...with capital a...to be 'app') when submitted?

   $(document).ready(function () {

   $('#submit').click(function () {

   ```
   var array = [];
   array[0] = ['AM', 'a.m.'];
   array[1] = ['PM', 'p.m.'];
   array[2] = ['application', 'app'];
   array[3] = ['cancelation', 'cancellation'];
   array[4] = ['crash', 'close'];
   array[5] = ['crashes', 'closes'];
   array[6] = ['crashing', 'closing'];
   array[7] = ['digital TV', 'smart TV'];
   array[8] = ['dropdown', 'drop-down'];
   array[9] = ['grey', 'gray'];
   array[10] = ['mbps', 'megabits per second'];
   array[11] = ['plugin', 'plug-in'];
   array[12] = ['normal', 'standard'];
   array[13] = ['is stuck', 'is frozen'];
   array[14] = ['gets stuck', 'freezes'];
   array[15] = ['wifi', 'Wi-Fi'];
   array[16] = ['TV\'s', 'TVs'];
   array[17] = ['Bluray', 'Blu-ray'];
   array[18] = ['Blu-Ray', 'Blu-ray'];
   array[19] = ['set top box', 'set-top box'];
   array[20] = ['choose', 'select'];
   array[21] = ['log in', 'sign in'];
   array[22] = ['log out', 'sign out'];
   array[23] = ['onscreen', 'on-screen'];
   array[24] = ['right hand', 'right'];
   array[25] = ['left hand', 'left'];

   $('#article').val(function (i, v) {
       $.each(array, function (i, arr) {
           v = v.replace(arr[0], arr[1]);
       })
       return v;
   });
   return false;
   ```

   });
   });

http://jsfiddle.net/sUY69/4/

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$('#article').val(function (index, value)
            {
                $.each(array, function (i, arr) {
                     value = value == arr[0] || value.toLowerCase() == arr[0] ? arr[1] : value;
                })
                return value;
            });
            return false;
```

Updated Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/sUY69/7/

Comment: Thank you so much. Is there a way to make it so if the term is in span tags the text replace still occurs? Only if the span has a class of "MFR_UIREF" it doesn't replace the text. All other instances it should replace the text.